# Turn off Visual Studio suggestions when using Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, refactoring, resharper

I just started playing with ReSharper and I think I know why ppl love it now :)

I'm using Vs2008 TS and noticed I have **in editor 2 suggestions currently**:
one, standard coming from VS, and second from ReSharper...

Eg when I entere something like:

```
int a = CalculateMe ( 10 );
```

(**Note:** CalculateMe method is not defined yet)
So, I can see VS's "option to generate method stub (shift + Alt + F10" and,
and RS's 'create methods CalculateMe')

I would like to see only ReSharper suggestions (turn off VS's) - is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's a way to do that.

I've been using ReSharper since version 1.5. I just ignore the little Visual Studio smart tag. It's quite unobtrusive.

Comment: This is annoying for me... Also I believe this consumes some CPU as well - so it would be better to switch it off...

Comment: I don't know of a way to shut it off. Also, believe me when I tell you that the amount of CPU and memory used by Visual Studio IntelliSense and refactoring is nothing compared to ReSharper.

Comment: @John Saunders Look when you open Solution-wide option